# Idiomatic Lisp way to create a list of sorted random numbers?

Tags: common-lisp, idioms

I'd like to find out what is the commonly accepted way to create a sorted list of random numbers in Common Lisp. In Clojure it is quite straightforward:

```
(sort (take 10 (repeatedly #(rand 10))))
```

I've found that in CL the following works:

```
(sort (loop for n below 10 collect (random 10)) #'<)
```

but does not read as well. Is there a cleaner way to express the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost:

```
(sort (loop repeat 10 collect (random 10)) #'<)
```

Comment: Didn't know about `repeat`. Small change but conceptually cleaner especially without the need to name a variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think that [sds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33004778/1281433) is a pretty good choice here, but there's also the potential to use the helpful [**map-into**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_map_in.htm), which could be valuable if you need to do this a lot, and can *reuse* one of your existing lists (or vectors).  It also has the advantage it separates the list generation code from the random number generation code;  if you need to increase the number of elements in the list, you don't have to modify the sorting or random number generation code.

```
(sort (map-into (make-list 10) #'(lambda () (random 10))) '<)
;=> (0 2 2 2 4 5 6 6 8 9)
```

```
(let ((l (make-list 10)))
  (sort (map-into l #'(lambda () (random 10))) '<))
;=> (1 1 3 3 4 6 7 8 8 9)
```